# Can not run evince. Says shared library is missing

Tags: evince, shared-library

When trying to start evince Ubuntu 12.04 responds me:

```
% evince
evince: error while loading shared libraries: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

On the other hand `ldd` reports no problems.

```
% ldd /usr/bin/evince
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa15ff000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f57bdb04000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f57bd8ea000)
    libevdocument3.so.4 => /usr/lib/libevdocument3.so.4 (0x00007f57bd6b5000)
        ...
```

I suppose there must be a problem with loading shared libraries. `libSM` is just a first one. Asking Ubuntu to be more verbose did not bring any idea to me.

```
% export LD_DEBUG=all
% evince
      6574: 
      6574: file=libSM.so.6 [0];  needed by evince [0]
      6574: find library=libSM.so.6 [0]; searching
      6574:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache <----- why not found?
      6574:  search path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib/tls/x86_64:/lib/tls:/lib/x86_64:/lib:/usr/lib/tls/x86_64:/usr/lib/tls:/usr/lib/x86_64:/usr/lib        (system search path)
      6574:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libSM.so.6
      6574:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libSM.so.6
      6574:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libSM.so.6
      6574:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6
      6574:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libSM.so.6
      6574:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libSM.so.6
      6574:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libSM.so.6
      6574:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 <----- why it fails?
      6574:   trying file=/lib/tls/x86_64/libSM.so.6
      6574:   trying file=/lib/tls/libSM.so.6
      6574:   trying file=/lib/x86_64/libSM.so.6
      6574:   trying file=/lib/libSM.so.6
      6574:   trying file=/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libSM.so.6
      6574:   trying file=/usr/lib/tls/libSM.so.6
      6574:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64/libSM.so.6
      6574:   trying file=/usr/lib/libSM.so.6
      6574: 
evince: error while loading shared libraries: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But

```
% unset LD_DEBUG
% ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 lip 25  2012 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 -> libSM.so.6.0.1
% ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6.0.1 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 30888 mar  2  2012 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6.0.1
```

Problem occurs with evince only. Other programs run flawlessly.

Regenerating `/etc/ld.so.cache` changes nothing.

```
% ldconfig
% ls -l /etc/ld.so.cache 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 84443 lis  6 17:17 /etc/ld.so.cache
% evince
evince: error while loading shared libraries: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

`gv` depends on `libSM` also and runs without problems. Let's compare

```
% gv
6605:     
      6605:     file=libXaw3d.so.6 [0];  needed by gv [0]
      6605:     find library=libXaw3d.so.6 [0]; searching
      6605:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      6605:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXaw3d.so.6
      6605:     
      6605:     file=libXaw3d.so.6 [0];  generating link map
      6605:       dynamic: 0x00007f1b68327b88  base: 0x00007f1b680d5000   size: 0x000000000025e560
      6605:         entry: 0x00007f1b680ea9e0  phdr: 0x00007f1b680d5040  phnum:                  7
      6605:     
...
      6605:     file=libSM.so.6 [0];  needed by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 [0]
      6605:     find library=libSM.so.6 [0]; searching
      6605:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      6605:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6
      6605:     
      6605:     file=libSM.so.6 [0];  generating link map
      6605:       dynamic: 0x00007f1b66e4fdb8  base: 0x00007f1b66c49000   size: 0x0000000000207158
      6605:         entry: 0x00007f1b66c4ab20  phdr: 0x00007f1b66c49040  phnum:                  7
      6605:     
...
```

Here loader finds entry in its cache.

Comment: Maybe you have to regenerate `/etc/ld.so.cache`, try with `ldconfig`.

Answer (score 0):

We can reproduce this issue on a 12.04 system with

`/usr/lib` a symlink (from ext4 mounted `/`) to `/usr1/lib` (ext3 mounted `/usr1`)

Moving `/usr1/lib` into `/usr` fixes the issue.

It happens with evince only, not other programs like `gv` which uses libSM

Did the original poster have split mounts/varying filesystems as well?