# Evince is not able to run (says missing shared libraries)

Tags: xubuntu, pdf, netbeans, evince

I've already looked [this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372050/can-not-run-evince-says-shared-library-is-missing) but that didn't resolve my issue. I'm on Xubuntu 16.04 and today when I started evince, I got this error:

```
evince: error while loading shared libraries: libevdocument3.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But ldd clearly says that the file is present:

```
ldd /usr/bin/evince|grep evdoc
libevdocument3.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevdocument3.so.4 (0x00007fcb32610000)
```

The debug output is as follows:

```
export LD_DEBUG=all
evince
     16254: 
     16254: WARNING: Unsupported flag value(s) of 0x8000000 in DT_FLAGS_1.
     16254: 
     16254: file=libevdocument3.so.4 [0];  needed by evince [0]
     16254: find library=libevdocument3.so.4 [0]; searching
     16254:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     16254:  search path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib/tls/x86_64:/lib/tls:/lib/x86_64:/lib:/usr/lib/tls/x86_64:/usr/lib/tls:/usr/lib/x86_64:/usr/lib        (system search path)
     16254:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libevdocument3.so.4
     16254:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libevdocument3.so.4
     16254:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libevdocument3.so.4
     16254:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevdocument3.so.4
     16254:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libevdocument3.so.4
     16254:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libevdocument3.so.4
     16254:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libevdocument3.so.4
     16254:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevdocument3.so.4
     16254:   trying file=/lib/tls/x86_64/libevdocument3.so.4
     16254:   trying file=/lib/tls/libevdocument3.so.4
     16254:   trying file=/lib/x86_64/libevdocument3.so.4
     16254:   trying file=/lib/libevdocument3.so.4
     16254:   trying file=/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libevdocument3.so.4
     16254:   trying file=/usr/lib/tls/libevdocument3.so.4
     16254:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64/libevdocument3.so.4
     16254:   trying file=/usr/lib/libevdocument3.so.4
     16254: 
evince: error while loading shared libraries: libevdocument3.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The strange thing is that yesterday Evince was working fine and today this suddenly happened! I've never installed/uninstalled any packages during this time. Only thing I've done is run a few apps like netbeans and android-studio (from my home directory). What could be the issue?

**edit**

```
prahlad@parrot:/data$ ls -ld / /usr /usr/lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevdocument3.so.4
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root  4096 Jun 13 13:26 /
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  4096 Oct 21  2015 /usr
drwxr-xr-x 139 root root 20480 Jul  6 22:50 /usr/lib
drwxr-xr-x 102 root root 90112 Jul 11 13:50 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    23 Mar  9 03:23 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevdocument3.so.4 -> libevdocument3.so.4.0.0

prahlad@parrot:/data$ file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevdocument3.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevdocument3.so.4: symbolic link to libevdocument3.so.4.0.0

prahlad@parrot:/data$ uname -a
Linux parrot 4.4.0-24-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 8 19:27:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
/data$
```

Comment: Look at `ls -ld / /usr /usr/lib  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevdocument3.so.4; file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevdocument3.so.4;uname -a`

Comment: @waltinator Updated post with the output of all the commands.

Comment: Wait, I'm thinking that the symlink that libevdocument3.so.4 points to (i.e. libevdocument3.so.4.0.0) is not executable (x), so could that be the case for failure? Is it the case that both the main file and its symlink BOTH should be executable?

Comment: Does the link target,  libevdocument3.so.4.0.0, exist?  Is it world readable? Forget executable, that's not needed.

Comment: Does running `sudo ldconfig` change anything? That rescans the dynamic library directories and updates their cache.

Comment: @ubfan1 Yes libevdocument3.so.4.0.0 exists and is world readable. Permissions are  `-rw-r--r--`.

Comment: @ByteCommander Thanks a lot, the issue got resolved today after I ran `sudo ldconfig`.

Comment: @PrahladYeri Great. Would you mind if I post that as my own answer and you remove yours, or do you want to keep it as it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shared library is where it should be, but maybe it did not get recognized and cached properly.

The command `ldconfig` scans all directories that are configured to contain such dynamic shared libraries and updates the library cache and links with what it found.

Simply run it like this:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

It should complete within a second or less and will fix problems related to missing shared library links and outdated library caches.